# DAX: Range filter result returns values not in range

Tags: powerbi, dax

I wrote a DAX measure (not calculated column) to filter out count based on range. However, the results also included those that didnt belong in the range. This measure will be used for card visual.

```
Customer_spending = CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT('Sales'[Customer Name]),FILTER('Sales', [Spending] >= 50000 ))

Spending = ([Return]/[Order])*1000000
```

Correct data should be shown as below. Which the total customer would be 11, however the result shows 45.

[image]

Is there a way to get the accurate data? I'm new to Power BI and still figuring this out for the whole day.

Answer (score 0):

Your measure definition is perfectly correct, Customer_spending measure corresponds correctly to the situation you have described. The problem is some where else, you should review your count.